# I am a beginner. Anyone please tell me How do I populate products in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, populate, mongoose-populate

```js
{
       "_id": "61b2e4d39568674384d4c472",
        "id": 2,
        "userId": "61b20b82e90d7041343242ba",
        "date": "2021-12-10T05:25:39.919Z",
        "products": [
            {
                "_id": "61b2e4d39568674384d4c473",
                "productId": "61b34b79666827160c6fde57",
                "quantity": 3
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Comment: I am a beginner. Anyone please tell me How do I populate products  in Mongoose? Also, If i have to populate both userId and products and then How would I would I do it?

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population